# Drop MongoDb collection and create with the old indexes

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring data to manage mongoDb collection and to remove all elements of some collections I'm using `mongoTemplate.dropCollection(Anomaly.class);` because the collection is too big to use the `deleteAll()` of CrudRepository.
The problem is the creation of the collection when a new document is added. The collection doesn't have the indexes (except the _id) despite the java class is correctly annotated:

```
@Field("anomaly_id")
@JsonProperty("anomaly_id")
@Indexed(unique = true)
private String anomalyId;
```

I tried with `mongoTemplate.createCollection(Anomaly.class)` with the same result, but if I restart tomcat on the startup the collection is created with the indexes.
How can I fix this problem?Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do index 2 way.
1. @index in field you want
2. Do it programly

Please refer to this ([Spring Data MongoDB - Where to create an index programmatically for a Mongo collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47055743/spring-data-mongodb-where-to-create-an-index-programmatically-for-a-mongo-coll))

because the collection is too big to use the  deleteAll(), you are doing bigdata probblem so maybe this won't help.